# How to aggregate all the resulted rows column data in one column?

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

I have a case driven query . Below is the simplest form

```
select Column 1 from mytable
```

**Results :**

```
    Column 1        
   latinnametest
   LatinManual
   LatinAuto
```

Is it possible to show the aggregated data of column 1 data of all the resulted rows in another Column say column 5 in front of each row with comma separated ?

**Expected :**

```
Column 1         Column 2
latinnametest  latinnametest,LatinManual,LatinAuto
LatinManual    latinnametest,LatinManual,LatinAuto
LatinAuto      latinnametest,LatinManual,LatinAuto
```

I have used *array_agg* and *concat()* but it aggregates the same row data in column 2  but not as expected to add all rows column data comma separated . Any help please.

**Edit :**
I have tried the solution mentioned below but I am getting repetitive data in the column . see the screenshot. I have hover the mouse over that last column and see the repetitive data . Any solution to this ?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks to bring this to my notice. It was my mistake to add it in the tag !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_agg()` as a window function:

```
select column_1, 
       string_agg(column_1, ',') over () as all_values
from the_table;
```

Edit, after the scope was changed:

If you need distinct values, use a derived table:

```
select column_1, 
       string_agg(column_1, ',') over () as all_values
from (
  select distinct column_1
  from the_table
) t;
```

Alternatively with a common table expression:

```
with vals as (
  select string_agg(distinct column_1, ',') as all_values
  from the_table 
)
select t.column_1, v.all_values
from the_table t
  cross join vals v
```

Comment: I did use this but , in that column I am getting data in large, same data is getting repeated . Any way to use distinct  ? It says `ERROR:  DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions
LINE 11:  string_agg(  distinct (case when `

Comment: Thanks I have integrate and it worked as expected . . Thanks alot